# Regex for cipher suite match

Tags: java, regex

I need to design a regex in java to match a list of cipher suites configured on a Java EE server, e.g.

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDH_ECDSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256, -TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA, TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256
```

The requirements are:

1. match all cipher suites contain the word RC4 or MD5 in the middle e.g. `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256`
2. match all cipher suites contain the word SHA at the end e.g. `TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`
3. Not to include cipher suite starting with the minus sign "-"

So the regex shall only match the following:
`TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA` (ending with SHA)
`TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA256` (with RC4 in the middle)

`-TLS_ECDH_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` shall not be included since it starts with "-".

I tried the following:

```
(?<!-)\b([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)\b(?<=RC4|MD5|SHA)
```

Which matches `SHA` at the end beautifully but doesn't work for `RC4` and `MD5` in the middle.

Would you please help to show me how to create such a regex? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Regex has many implementations that works slightly different. Which programming language/regex dialect is it?

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/ or similar and share your example.

Comment: Java is the programming language. regex101.com is my favourite website to test regex, however, my knowledge of regex is limited so I need to learn more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be using `\w` to match word characters.

```
(?<!-)\b(?:\w+(?:RC4|MD5)\w+|\w+SHA)\b
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<!-)` Negative lookbehind to assert not `-` to the left
- `\b` A word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\w+(?:RC4|MD5)\w+` match 1+ word characters, 1 of the alternatives and 1+ word characters as either one of the alternatives is in "the middle" (not at the beginning or end)
  - `|` Or
  - `\w+SHA` match 1+ word characters and match `SHA`
- `)\b` Close non capture group followed by a word boundary

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/R6doik/1)

To not match consecutive underscores, you could match word characters without the underscore `[^\W_]+` using a negated character class followed by an underscore `_`

```
(?<!-)\b(?:(?:[^\W_]+_)+(?:RC4|MD5)(?:_[^\W_]+)+|(?:[^\W_]+_)+SHA)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/C05MRE/1)

Comment: Thanks @The fourth bird a lot. That helps.